# Flex 4 INLINE Layout help required

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

In FLEX 4 Layout, how can one display a sequence of images, text, other object types INLINE wrt each other. For example: 
TEXT1 IMAGE1 OBJECT1 (END OF LINE)
(NEW LINE)  ABCTEXT3 (END OF LINE) 
(NEW LINE) XOBJECT2  (END OF LINE)

The horizontal span is not fixed for any element. 
Vertical span is not a constraint. 
Just that elements should follow each other INLINE.

Answer (score 0):

HGroups and VGroups are your answer, if I understand the question. From what I see you want a top level vertical layout with 3 HGroups contained in it. Below is an example. (Instead of setting layout on the application you could also wrap the HGroups in a VGroup. It all depends on where you are using this code)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Label text="Item 1, Line 1" />
        <s:Label text="Item 2, Line 1" />
        <s:Label text="Item 3, Line 1" />
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Label text="Item 4, Line 2" />
        <s:Label text="Item 5, Line 2" />
        <s:Label text="Item 6, Line 2" />
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Label text="Item 7, Line 3" />
        <s:Label text="Item 8, Line 3" />
        <s:Label text="Item 9, Line 3" />
    </s:HGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the TileGroup.

That will automatically wrap your items, though it does so in a grid format. If you want each line to be horizontally aligned I'm not sure how to do that. That's what I'm looking for at the moment!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for those who find this page with the same problem, check here:

[Inline-Style Flow Custom Layout Example](http://evtimmy.com/2009/06/flowlayout-a-spark-custom-layout-example/)

This is the best way to have items flow inline and wrap around to a new line. Can I have a tick now?